# Unable to start Xcode Profiler, Error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)

Tags: ios, xcode, profiling, watchkit

Unable to start profiler, and getting an error as below.

```
Write auxiliary files

/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/i386
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build/Objects-normal/i386 (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build/Objects-normal/i386
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build/Objects-normal/i386 (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
/bin/mkdir -p /WinWorker\ WatchApp\ Extension.build
error: Unable to create directory: /<App name> WatchApp Extension.build (Permission denied)
```

Any help???.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you specified the root (/) directory as an absolute build location.

Since your user account appropriately doesn't have permission to create directories there, the build fails.

Go to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations and [change the build location](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-locations_preferences/Build/Build.html).

[image]